# What is Prefered Implementation Approach for Zend Acl

Tags: singleton, zend-acl, zend-framework

In Zend Framework 1.X which of the following approaches is better and why?
**Approach-1:**
Create a (sub)Class extending Zend_Acl and use is to manage all the Acl. It will allow us to use all the Zend_Acl features/function using $this object.

**Approach-2:**
Create a Custom Class which holds Zend_Acl object and perform actions on the object. Here we can create wrapper functions and can control the access to Zend_Acl's base functions and use only a handful features.

Singleton pattern can be used for both approaches as well to make sure that throughout the site, same Zend_Acl is used.

I will looking for an approach which I can later port to ZF-2.0 easily. If there is any-other approach, please mention it and I will update the post accordingly.

**Update:** Are there any approaches other thn singleton to maintain single Zend_Acl object throughout the site? And what do you think about using a singleton with approach-1 and use custom methods as well, which will give us all the predefined methods of Zend_Acl along with our custom wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

> I will looking for an approach which I can later port to ZF-2.0 easily. If there is any-other approach, please mention it and I will update the post accordingly.

This remark strongly favors approach 2, since your wrapper acts as an adapter to the ACL implementation, and your application interacts only with your adapter, not `Zend_Acl` directly. Thus you can later change the specific implementation (i.e. composition of `Zend_Acl`) to another one, be it `Zend\Acl` or a Symfony 2 component or something you write yourself..

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use a Model to manage the whole ACL system (add resources, add roles and so on). Obviously this class extends Zend_Acl. Moreover I use a plugin, that use a preDispatch method, to check if the user who made the request is allowed to access the requested url or not.